# partial derivative of sum and product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, products

I would like to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial f_i} \prod_{j=1}^N f_j$, where $1\le i\le N$. By typing e.g.

```
F[f_] = Product[f[i], {i, 1, N}]
D[F[f], f[1]]
```

Mathematica returns zero. On the other side, by replacing the product with a sum

```
F[f_] = Sum[f[i], {i, 1, N}]
D[F[f], f[1]]
```

I get $1$ as expected. What is the effective difference among the two expressions? I would like to keep $N$ implicit, without assigning any fixed integer value.

Comment: `D[Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 5}], f[1]]`  `D[Product[f[i], {i, 1, 5}], f[1]]`

Comment: Is it possible to keep in both cases the upper bound $N$ implicit?

Comment: Your asking for a product and sum rule with chain rule: [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) in the section Scope->Symbolic functions. I f is given in a function know to Mathematica N can be choosen free. If f in symbolic it has to be done be hand. Symbolic pair f, N is evaluated lazy by Mathematica. Look at [`Produkt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html) how this is implemented in detail.

Comment: In MMA "N" is a function. The naming convention in MMA is, that built in symbols start with a capital. To prevent collisions, you should only use variable names that start with a lower case character.

Comment: Further," Product" needs a numeric upper index, otherwise it will not evaluate.

Comment: I found that passing to $\prod_j f_j = \sum_j e^{\log f_j}$, for positive $f_j$, solves the issue, hence it allows me to fix a generic upper bound. This way one can make use of the more general applicability of Sum, rather than Product